# Filtering Children in Entity Framework Query

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, database, entity-framework

I have a database which it's schema is as follows:

[image: Database Schema]

As you can see, We have **WareCategories** which will be category of the wares i'm going to be working in my website. **WareTypes** which will be Definition of each Item type. Categories define properties in the table **WarePropertyDefinitions** and **WareProperties** define values for each property that has been defined in **WarePropertyDefinitions** table.

Now i have a search page that users search for items in **OldWares** and user selects category and i show the user all properties defined in **WarePropertyDefinitions** and user fills the data if he likes better results. But my problem is that i can't filter **WareTypes** based on **WareProperties** because it's from the type **ICollection** and i can't access filter options.

How can i apply this kind of filtering based on properties?

Thanks in advance...

Edit:

This is a part of the code i'm presenting to describe more:

```
var lst = WareCategory.GetItem(Convert.ToInt32(ddlChildren.SelectedValue)).WarePropertyDefinitions.ToList();
                foreach (var ListItem in lst)
                {
                        var value = BaseHelper.FindFormValue("PropertyValue" + ListItem.Id.ToString());
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
                        {
                            query = query.Where(m => m.WareType.WareProperties.);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

This segment of code is in my search function and as you can see i'm going to generate a list of items in **WarePropertyDefinition** that user selected via a drop down menu called **ddlChildren**. I'm going to iterate in this definition and user entered value for each property (the **value** variable will hold the value user entered and i will check if user have entered anything in the textbox) i will include it in where section (through this i will add it in where clause that ultimately filters my selection). but as you can see the code is incomplete because i don't know how to complete it.

Comment: adding some  code to your question will let us understand the issue more.

Comment: I have edited my code, if you need more of my code i will gladly provide more, but i think this part of the code is enough. thanks in advance

Comment: so you want to find WareTypes where WareProperties Id has value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Any() extension method, for example:

```
query = query.Where(m => m.WareType.WareProperties.Any(wp => wp.Id == 5));
```

Comment: i fixed it by the this code: query = query.Where(m => m.WareType.WareProperties.Any(wp => wp.WarePropertyDefinition_Id == ListItem.Id && wp.TextValue == value));

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the my problem by this code:

```
query = query.Where(m => m.WareType.WareProperties.Any(wp => wp.WarePropertyDefinition_Id == ListItem.Id && wp.TextValue == value));
```

but because @user3159792's answer was the basic of my problem i have selected his answer as the default answer to my problem. very thanks.